# Numpy memory mapping issue

Tags: python, numpy

I've been recently working with large matrices. My inputs are stored in form of 15GB `.npz` files, which I am trying to read incrementally, in small batches.

I am familiar with memory mapping, and having seen `numpy` also supports these kinds of operations seemed like a perfect solution. However, the problem I am facing is as follows:

I first load the matrix with:

```
foo = np.load('matrix.npz',mmap_mode="r+")
```

`foo` has a single key: `data`.

When I try to, for example do:

```
foo['data'][1][1]
```

`numpy` seems to endlessly spend  the available RAM, almost as if there were no memory mapping. Am I doing anything wrong?

My goal would be, for example, to read 30 lines at a time:

```
for x in np.arange(0,matrix.shape[1],30):
    batch = matrix[x:(x+30),:]
    do_something_with(batch)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that `mmap_mode="r+"` is ignored when the file in question is a zipped numpy file.  I haven't used numpy in this way, so some of what follows is my best guess. The documentation for [load](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) states

> If the file is a .npz file, then a dictionary-like object is returned, containing {filename: array} key-value pairs, one for each file in the archive.

No mention of what it does with `mmap_mode`.  However in the [code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.0/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L280-L446) for loading `.npz` files no usage is made of the `mmap_mode` keyword:

```
    if magic.startswith(_ZIP_PREFIX):
        # zip-file (assume .npz)
        # Transfer file ownership to NpzFile
        tmp = own_fid
        own_fid = False
        return NpzFile(fid, own_fid=tmp, allow_pickle=allow_pickle, pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
```

So, your initial guess is indeed correct.  Numpy uses all of the ram because there is no memmapping ocurring.  This is a limitation of the implementation of `load`; since the `npz` format is an uncompressed zip archive it should be possible to memmap the variables (unless of course your files were created with `savez_compressed`).

Implementing a load function that memmaps `npz` would be quite a bit of work though, so you may want to take a look at [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.rec.html).  They provide similar usage (access of fields by keys) and are already compatible with memmapping.

Comment: Having just checked the code, this is indeed the case. Thanks!